# Dialing phone dependently on location in Swift

Tags: swift, nsurl, tel

I have phone numbers in the form:

> (+39) 0765 87...
>
> +41 (0)33 - 675 ...

whose meaning is of course to discharge the part in parenthesis in the first case when performing a local call, in the latter when performing an international call.
If I pass either to NSURL(string:) I get nil. How is it possible to get the right behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to first remove all occurrences of `(0)` and then remove all brackets and trailing zeroes to the `)`. Even if you're calling a local number, you can use the country prefix just fine.

Something like this, but you could probably write it with regular expressions.

```
var number = "(+39) 0765 87"

number = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
number = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(0)", withString: "")
number = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString: "")
number = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")0", withString: "")
number = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")
```

Comment: In fact I temporarily did:

Comment: That I did, in fact. Yet it does not work for intention calls and specifically for England not even for local calls.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I temporally did:

```
let myStringArr = phoneValueLabel.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(")")
var strippedStr:String!
if myStringArr.count==2{
    strippedStr = myStringArr[1]
} else {
    strippedStr = phoneValueLabel.text!
}
let trimmedString = strippedStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
let phoneLink="tel://\(trimmedString)"
let url=NSURL(string:phoneLink)
print("phoneLink=\(phoneLink) url=\(url)")
if (url != nil){
    phoneValueLabel.addLink(url: url!, atRange:range)
}
```

in order to strip all characters beef the closing parentheses. This of course work for a local call, though. What I was looking for was a solution inserting the right code according to whether the call was local or international. To have for instance:

033 675...
if the call was from England and, for instance:
0041 33 675 if the call were from Italy.

For that matter my solution does not work for England as trimming all characters before the closing parentheses also trims the necessary 0.